# Ist der Gebrauch von [æ] (bzw. Ä) im Schweizerdeutschen ungewöhnlich?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect, swiss-german

In schweizerdeutschen Dialekten wird das Zeichen [æ] des Internationalen Phonetischen Alphabets (bzw. der Buchstabe Ä in alltäglicher Verschriftlichung) oft für einen Laut wie in den folgenden zürichdeutschen Wörtern gebraucht (anklicken für Audio-Aufnahme):

- [Wääg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gsw-z%C3%BCrit%C3%BC%C3%BCtsch-W%C3%A4g.ogg) ‘Weg’
- [gääl](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gsw-z%C3%BCrit%C3%BC%C3%BCtsch-g%C3%A4%C3%A4l.ogg) ‘gelb’

Der Gebrauch des Zeichens [æ] (das ja gewissermassen dem Buchstaben Ä entspricht) für diesen Laut ist auf jeden Fall traditionell üblich, vgl. [ɡ̊æːl] in [Zurich German](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0025100306002441).

Was ich mich schon lange frage: Könnte es sich um eine schweizerische Besonderheit handeln, dass dieser Laut mit [æ] (bzw. Ä) wiedergegeben wird? Könnte es nicht sein, dass dieser Laut ausserhalb der Schweiz viel eher mit [a] (bzw. A) wiedergegeben würde?

Was mich insbesondere darauf bringt, ist der Gebrauch von A für einen gleichartigen Laut im Elsässischen (anklicken für Audio-Aufnahme):

- [der Waag](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gsw-oberels%C3%A4ssisch_(Z%C3%ACllesa)-d%27r_Wag.oga) ‘der Weg’
- [gaal](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gsw-oberels%C3%A4ssisch_(Z%C3%ACllesa)-gaal.oga) ‘gelb’

Ein weiteres Argument ist das Design des IPA-Vokaltrapezes, wonach das Zeichen [a] für den offensten und vordersten Laut stehen sollte. Beim Sprechen fühlt sich der Laut aus Wörtern wie zürichdeutsch «Wääg» weiter vorne und offener an als gewöhnliches A oder Ä. Zudem wird der Laut ein «überoffenes» E oder Ä genannt, was ebenfalls impliziert, dass es sich um den offensten Vokal handelt.

Comment: In den mir bekannten südhessischen (Odenwälder) Dialekten lauten diese Worte "gääl" und "Wääch" (mit möglichen lokalen Unterschieden), lautlich deutlich verschieden von "Gaal" und "Waach". Insofern ist es aus meiner Sicht eher das Elsässische, das heraussticht.

Comment: Verschriftlichung von Dialekten ist mangels Standard immer eine Näherung. Das verlinkte "gaal" hört sich in vielen südwestdeutschen Dialekten identisch zum Elsässischen an, wird aber normalerweise als "gääl" oder "gäel" transkribiert. Außerdem würde ich im Sinn haben wollen, dass die armen Elsässer vom "Office pour la Culture et la langue d'Alsace" im Gegensatz zu den Deutschen und Schweizern beim Schreiben ihres Dialekts kein "Ä" auf ihrer Tastatur finden...

Comment: @tofro: Danke für den Hinweis auf die Verschriftlichung. Ich habe die Frage mit stärkerem Fokus auf das IPA umformuliert – das ja einen Standard darstellt. Im Übrigen sieht die Orthal-Verschriftlichung für das Elsässische durchaus auch den Buchstaben Ä vor (und mit französischen Tastaturen lässt er sich auch eingeben), und zwar ähnlich wie im Standarddeutschen für den Laut [ɛ].

Comment: Warum sollte ein staatliches französisches staatliches Institut beim Transkribieren einer anerkannten Nationalsprache, die keine Schrift kennt, einen deutschen oder schweizerischen (oder österreichischen) Buchstaben verwenden, nur weil der dem gewünschten Laut eher entspricht? Es gibt sicher z.B. arabische Buchstaben, die dem gewünschten Laut noch mehr entsprechen.

Comment: Schaut man sich die Seite der OLCA an, findet man kein einziges 'ä' - Um das ein bisschen zu verdeutlichen, den "Gepäckträger" transkribiert man dort z.B. mit "*d'r Gepacktrajer*" - Das scheint also durchaus Absicht zu sein. (https://www.olcalsace.org/sites/default/files/lexique_auto.pdf)

Comment: @tofro: Ä wird nach Orthal durchaus verwendet (gem. [livret_orthal_2021.pdf](https://www.olcalsace.org/sites/default/files/publications/livret_orthal_2021.pdf) in Wörtern wie «wähle», «Mäwel», «Bäck», ) und kommt auch in dem von dir verlinkten Auto-Dokument vor (z.B. in «Formàlitäte», «wärme»). Ganz ähnlich wie Zürichdeutsch scheint das Elsässische zwei verschiedene Ä-Laute zu haben, einen, der in etwa standarddeutschem Ä [ɛ] entspricht, und einen «überoffenen» – und ich frage eben danach, ob der überoffene wirklich ein [æ] ist, und nicht eher ein [a].

Comment: Ein Laut zwischen *a* und *ä* in Hörbeispielen kann abhängig vom Sprecher und von den Hörgewohnheiten des Hörers als das eine oder das andere wahrgenommen werden, insbesondere wenn die Unterscheidung in der eigenen Sprache nicht vorkommt oder nicht relevant ist. Die Wahl des IPA-Zeichens kann auch davon abhängen, welche Unterscheidung von ähnlichen Lauten in der Sprache nötig ist.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt nicht "das Elsässische", dem "das Schweizerdeutsche" oder andere Dialekte gegenüberstehen. Dialekte gehen kontinuierlich ineinander über und verändern sich auch innerhalb der (künstlich gezogenen und in Wirklichkeit inexistenten) Dialektgrenzen oft von Ort zu Ort.

Die Aussprache des Elsässischen ist nicht überall einheitlich, sondern verändert sich von Region zu Region. So wird das Wort <Baum>, von Süden nach Norden, unterschiedlich ausgesprochen:

> Bäum, Bàuim, Bauim, Baum, Baam, Bààm, Bœm (Quelle: [Guide pour écrire et lire l’Alsacien](https://www.olcalsace.org/sites/default/files/publications/livret_orthal_2021.pdf))

Wie du siehst, ist die Aussprache in der Nähe der Schweiz teilweise auch dem Schweizerdeutschen ähnlich* (mit [æː], geschrieben als <ä>), während weiter im Norden die Artikulation weiter nach vorne verschoben und zentraler und offener wird und sich zu [aː] (geschrieben <aa>) und [ɐː] (<àà>) verändert.

Insgesamt finden wir im deutschen Sprachraum einen kontinuierlichen Übergang von /æː/ zu /eː/ von Südwesten nach Norden, wie z.B. bei <Weg>, das in der Schweiz /væːɡ/ und in Schleswig-Holstein /veːç/ gesprochen wird.

Insofern hat du recht. Die Aussprache des Phonems /eː/ als [æː] ist eine Besonderheit des äußersten südwestdeutschen Sprachraums. Weiter im Norden verändert sich die Aussprache – wie im Elsässischen über [aː] und [ɐː] – hin zu [eː].

---

* Der Diphthong /aʊ̯/ folgt einem anderen Verlauf als der Monophthong /eː/. Ich benutze das Beispiel des Elsässischen <Baum> nur um den Verlauf der Aussprache des [æ] zu [ɐː] im Elsässischen zu illustrieren, weil mir Quellen für die Aussprache von <Weg> fehlen.

Hinweis: <...> Graphem, /.../ Phonem, [...] Allophon

Answer (score -1):

Ich kann leider nichts zu schweizerischen Dialekten sagen, möchte aber zu den IPA-Lautzeichen etwas sagen. Es gibt da nämlich ein kleines Problem bei dem Laut, der im Deutschen üblicherweise mit dem Buchstaben A verknüpft ist. Dieser Laut wird fast immer mit dem IPA-Symbol [a] wiedergegeben, was aber eigentlich falsch ist:

Auf Wikipedia gibt es eine hervorragende [Liste der IPA-Zeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen). Und da steht beim allersten Zeichen in der Liste (beim [a]) folgendes  (Hervorhebung von mir):

| IPA-Zeichen | Laut | Umschreibung für Deutschsprachige | Beispiel | Hörbeispiel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **[a]** | [Ungerundeter offener Vorderzungenvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungerundeter_offener_Vorderzungenvokal) | **der Laut kommt im Deutschen nicht vor;** das IPA-Zeichen wird allerdings oft vereinfachend für den [ungerundeten offenen Zentralvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungerundeter_offener_Zentralvokal) benutzt, welcher die deutsche Standardaussprache des a ist | deutsch **Kamm** [kʰam]; frz. **avoir** (haben) [aˈvwa:ʁ]; russ. **я** (ich) [ja] | [▶](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Open_front_unrounded_vowel.ogg) |

Das in der deutschen Lautschrift so gut wie immer verwendete Symbol [a] bezeichnet also einen Laut, den es im Deutschen gar nicht gibt. Der Laut, der tatsächlich verwendet wird, hat eine eigene Wikipedia-Seite ([Ungerundeter offener Zentralvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungerundeter_offener_Zentralvokal)) und da steht folgendes (Hervorhebung von mir):

> Der ungerundete offene Zentralvokal (UoZ) ist im Deutschen bei der (Standard-)Aussprache des Buchstabens  gebräuchlich. **Für diesen Laut existiert kein offizielles IPA-Zeichen.**

Gleich darunter befindet sich eine Liste der in der Praxis verwendeten Ersatzzeichen. (Auf Wikipedia ist es eine Liste, ich gebe es hier als Tabelle wieder):

| IPA-Zeichen | Beschreibung | Kommentar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **[a]** | das IPA-Zeichen für den [ungerundeten offenen Vorderzungenvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungerundeter_offener_Vorderzungenvokal) (UoV) | Dies ist die am häufigsten gewählte schriftliche Realisierung. Die Verwendung des IPA-Zeichens [a] ist einer der Gründe, warum der UoZ häufig mit dem UoV verwechselt wird oder aber die beiden Laute gar nicht erst unterschieden werden. |
| **[ä]** | zusammengesetzt aus dem o. g. IPA-Zeichen [a] für den UoV und einem Trema (¨) als dem diakritischen Zeichen für Zentralisierung/Vokalabschwächung | Wegen der Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem Umlaut-Zeichen <ä>, das in der Regel der Aussprache [ɛ] entspricht (siehe ungerundeter halboffener Vorderzungenvokal, UhV), wird dieses Zeichen seltener verwendet. |
| **[ᴀ]** | das Kapitälchen-A | Wird regelmäßig verwendet. |

Der Aussage, dass das Kapitälchen-A (ᴀ) regelmäßig verwendet wird, möchte ich heftig widersprechen. Ich habe es noch nie in einer Lautschrift gesehen und es wird in der [Liste der IPA-Zeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen) auch gar nicht angeführt.

Wenn man streng den IPA-Regeln folgt, müsste man daher den Laut, den deutsche Muttersprachler machen, wenn Sie den Buchstaben A aussprechen, als [ä] schreiben, denn dieses Symbol bedeutet eigentlich: *»zentralisierter ungerundeter offener Vorderzungenvokal«* Und weil ein Vorderzungenvokal, den man zentralisiert, in Wahrheit ein Zentralvokal ist, beschreibt das Symbol [ä] eigentlich ganz genau den fraglichen Laut, nämlich den ungerundeten offenen Zentralvokal.

Unglücklicherweise schaut aber das Symbol [ä] exakt gleich aus wie der deutsche Buchstabe »ä«, der aber eben genau **nicht** als ungerundeten offenen Zentralvokal ausgesprochen wird, sondern - je nach geografischer Region als [ɛ] oder [e]. (In nördlicheren Regionen vorwiegend als [ɛ] = ungerundeter halboffener Vorderzungenvokal wie in *»kess«;* in südlicheren Regionen vorwiegend als [e] = ungerundeter halbgeschlossener Vorderzungenvokal wie in *»See«*).

Nachdem das Symbol [ᴀ] in der Praxis aus mir unbekannten Gründen verschmäht wird, und das Symbol [ä] zu Verwechslungen führen würde, verwendet man eben so gut wie immer das eigentlich falsche Symbol [a].

---

Über das Symbol [​æ​] (eine Ligatur der Buchstaben a und e) steht in der [Liste der IPA-Zeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen) folgendes:

| IPA-Zeichen | Laut | Umschreibung | Beispiel | Hörbeispiel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **[​æ​]** | [Ungerundeter fast offener Vorderzungenvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungerundeter_fast_offener_Vorderzungenvokal) | offenes etwas helles a, zwischen a und ä [ɛ] | schweiz. **Estrich** (Dachboden) [ˈæʃtrɪx] (einige, nicht alle Dialekte); engl. **cat** (Katze) [kʰæt]; finn. **pää** (Kopf; Ende) [ˈpæː]; persisch **ابر** (Wolke) [æbɾ] | [▶](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel.ogg) |

Der Laut [​æ​] kommt daher offensichtlich innerhalb des deutschen Sprachraums nur in einigen (nicht allen!) schweizerischen Dialekten vor und steht zwischen dem Laut, der im Norden des deutschen Sprachraums für den Buchstaben »ä« verwendet wird (gemeint ist der Laut [ɛ]) und jenem Laut, der mit dem Symbol [a] wiedergegeben wird, von dem wir ja gerade gelernt haben, dass es diesen Laut im Deutschen gar nicht gibt.

Wir haben also diese Reihe (von A zu E):

| Symbol | Bezeichnung | Kommentar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ä] | ungerundeter offener Zentralvokal (eigentlich: zentralisierter ungerundeter offener Vorderzungenvokal) | Das ist der Laut, den deutsche Muttersprachler für den Buchstaben A verwenden. |
| [a] | ungerundeter offener Vorderzungenvokal | Dieser Laut kommt im Deutschen gar nicht vor, das Symbol wird aber trotzdem verwendet. |
| [​æ] | Ungerundeter fast offener Vorderzungenvokal | Dieser Laut kommt in einigen Schweizer Dialekten vor. |
| [ɛ] | Ungerundeter halboffener Vorderzungenvokal | Die mittel- und norddeutsche Aussprachevariante für den Buchstaben Ä |
| [e] | Ungerundeter halbgeschlossener Vorderzungenvokal | Die deutsche Standard-Aussprache für den Buchstaben E und die süddeutsche, und österreichische Aussprachevariante für den Buchstaben Ä |

<sup>Mir ist leider nicht bekannt, wie im Schweizerischen Standarddeutsch der Buchstaben Ä ausgesprochen wird. Ich vermute, dass das, wie in Österreich, der Laut [e] ist, bin mir da aber nicht sicher.</sup>
<sup>Der nächste Laut in dieser Liste wäre der *ungerundete geschlossene Vorderzungenvokal,* der eine der möglichen Aussprachen des Buchstaben I ist (IPA-Symbol: [i])</sup>

Ich hoffe, dass diese Beschreibung der Laute, ihrer IPA-Symbole und ihrer Verwendung ein wenig dazu beiträgt, dass man auch die Lautschrift versteht, die für Schweizer Dialekte verwendet wird.

Comment: Und was hörst du denn bei den verlinkten Audio-Aufnahmen?

Comment: Ich bin nicht allzu vertraut mit IPA Symbolen, aber als gebürtiger Zürcher kenne ich verschiedenste Schweizer Akzente, als auch das Schweizerische Standarddeutsch, sehr gut. In der Tat wird im Schweizerischen Standarddeutsch ein geschriebenes "ä" in der Regel als [​æ] ausgesprochen. Dem "Bär" sagen wir [​ʙæ:​r], während es im Hochdeutschen wohl eher ein [​ʙɛä] ist.

Comment: @kscherrer: Erstens: Schweizerisches Standarddeutsch **IST** Hochdeutsch. Zu sagen, dass etwas im Schweizerischen Standarddeutsch anders klingt als auf Hochdeutsch ist als würde man sagen, dass Bernhardiner anders bellen als Hunde. Ebenso wie österreichisches Standarddeutsch Hochdeutsch ist und natürlich auch das deutsche Standarddeutsch. Die drei Standardvarietäten stehen gleichberechtigt, gleichrangig und gleichwertig nebeneinander auf derselben Stufe und sind alle drei Varietäten derselben Sprache. ...

Comment: ... Zweitens: Der Bär wird in nördlichen Gebieten Deutschlands nicht als [ʙɛä] sondern vorwiegend als [bɛːɐ̯] ausgesprochen: Das Zeichen, das Ähnlichkeiten mit einem Doppelpunkt hat, markiert den davor stehenden Vokal als verlängert. Sas auf dem Kopf stehende a ist einer der beiden Schwa-Laute (derselbe Laut, der am Ende von *Lehrer, jeder* und *der* zu hören ist), und der Bogen darunter will sagen, dass der Laut, unter dem er steht, nicht der Kern eine eigenen Silbe ist. Der Schwa-Laut ist also der zweite Laut eines Diphthongs. ...

Comment: ... Im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums (z.B. in Österreich, wo ich lebe) wird der Bär hingegen vorwiegend als [beːɐ̯] ausgesprochen weil hier der Laut [ɛ] generell durch [e] ersetzt wird. (Bei uns klingen die Sätze *»Im Wald sind Beeren«* und *»Im Wald sind Bären.« *genau gleich.) (Das triofft hauptsächlich auf ältere Menschen zu. Junge ÖsterreicherInnen differenzieren seit wenigen Jahren bereits zwischen [ɛ] und [e])

Comment: @user52445: Alle in der Schweiz heimischen deutschen Dialekte sind allemannische Dialekte. Alle allemannischen Dialekte sind oberdeutschen Dialekte. Alle oberdeutschen Dialekte sind hochdeutsche Dialekte. Hochdeutsche Dialekte teil man in 2 Gruppen: mitteldeutschen und oberdeutsche Dialekte. Der Begriff *»Hochdeutsch«* ist mehrdeutig. Damit können hochdeutsche Dialekte gemeint sein (zu denen die allemannischen Dialekte gehören), aber mit *»Hochdeutsch«* kann auch *Standarddeutsch* gemeint ...

Comment: ... sein (das ist auch die für gewöhnlich gemeinte Bedeutung in einem alltagssprachlichen Kontext). Standarddeutsch ist standardisiertes Deutsch, also eine Variatät, die Unterrichtssprache an Schulen und Universitäten ist, und die an Schulen ein Unterrichtsfach ist. In einer standardisierten Sprache werden Gesetze und Tageszeitungen verfasst. Schweizerisches Standarddeutsch **IST** natürlich eine Standardvarietät der deutschen Sprache, und in diesem Sinne ist Schweizerisches Standardeutsch selbstverständlich Hochdeutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast D'accord. ``